# VBA code to read tables from Word document

Tags: vba, excel

Need help to modify this VBA code to read multiple tables from a Word document. It only reads one table, but I would like to import more than one into the same Excel sheet.

```
Sub ImportWordTables()
   'Imports a table from Word document 

   Dim wdDoc         As Object
   Dim wdFileName    As Variant
   Dim TableNo       As Integer  'number of tables in Word doc
   Dim iTable        As Integer  'table number index
   Dim iRow          As Long     'row index in Excel
   Dim iCol          As Integer  'column index in Excel

   wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc*),*.doc*", , _
     "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

   If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

   Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)   'open Word file

   With wdDoc
      TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
      If TableNo = 0 Then
         MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
         vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
      ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
         TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
         "Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
      End If
      With .tables(TableNo)
         'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
         For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
               Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
            Next iCol
         Next iRow
      End With
   End With
   Set wdDoc = Nothing       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is the code, but it doesn't entirely answer my questions.
I just need the tables from the pdf.

```
Sub Imp_Into_XL(PDF_File As String, Each_Sheet As Boolean)

'This procedure get the PDF data into excel by following way

'1.Open PDF file
'2.Looping through pages
'3.get the each PDF page data into individual _
  sheets or single sheet as defined in Each_Sheet Parameter


Dim AC_PD As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc              'access pdf file
Dim AC_Hi As Acrobat.AcroHiliteList         'set selection word count
Dim AC_PG As Acrobat.AcroPDPage             'get the particular page
Dim AC_PGTxt As Acrobat.AcroPDTextSelect    'get the text of selection area

Dim WS_PDF As Worksheet
Dim RW_Ct As Long                           'row count
Dim Col_Num As Integer                      'column count
Dim Li_Row As Long                          'Maximum rows limit for one column
Dim Yes_Fir As Boolean                      'to identify beginning of page

Li_Row = Rows.Count

Dim Ct_Page As Long                         'count pages in pdf file
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long         'looping variables
Dim T_Str As String

Dim Hld_Txt As Variant                      'get PDF total text into array

RW_Ct = 0                                   'set the intial value
Col_Num = 1                                 'set the intial value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set AC_PD = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Set AC_Hi = New Acrobat.AcroHiliteList

'set maximum selection area of PDF page

AC_Hi.Add 0, 32767

With AC_PD

    'open PDF file

    .Open PDF_File

    'get the number of pages of PDF file

    Ct_Page = .GetNumPages

    'if get pages is failed exit sub

    If Ct_Page = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Pages Cannot determine in PDF file '" & PDF_File & "'"
        .Close
        GoTo h_end
    End If

    'add sheet only one time if Data retrive in one sheet

    If Each_Sheet = False Then
        Set WS_PDF = Worksheets.Add(, Worksheets(Sheets.Count))
        WS_PDF.Name = "PDF3Text"
    End If

    'looping through sheets

    For i = 1 To Ct_Page

        T_Str = ""
        'get the page
        Set AC_PG = .AcquirePage(i - 1)

        'get the full page selection
        Set AC_PGTxt = AC_PG.CreateWordHilite(AC_Hi)

        'if text selected successfully get the all the text into T_Str string

        If Not AC_PGTxt Is Nothing Then

            With AC_PGTxt

                For j = 0 To .GetNumText - 1
                    T_Str = T_Str & .GetText(j)
                Next j

            End With

        End If


        If Each_Sheet = True Then

            'add each sheet for each page

            Set WS_PDF = Worksheets.Add(, Worksheets(Sheets.Count))

        End If

        'transfer PDF data into sheet

        With WS_PDF

            If Each_Sheet = True Then

                .Name = "Page-" & i

                'get the PDF data into each sheet for each PDF page

                'if text accessed successfully then split T_Str by VbCrLf
                'and get into array Hld_Txt and looping through array and fill sheet with PDF data

                If T_Str <> "" Then
                    Hld_Txt = Split(T_Str, vbCrLf)

                    For k = 0 To UBound(Hld_Txt)
                        T_Str = CStr(Hld_Txt(k))
                        If Left(T_Str, 1) = "=" Then T_Str = "'" & T_Str
                        .Cells(k + 1, 1).Value = T_Str
                    Next k
                        Else

                            'information if text not retrive from PDF page

                            .Cells(1, 1).Value = "No text found in page " & i
                End If

                    Else

                        'get the pdf data into single sheet

                        If T_Str <> "" Then
                            Hld_Txt = Split(T_Str, vbCrLf)

                            Yes_Fir = True

                            For k = 0 To UBound(Hld_Txt)

                                RW_Ct = RW_Ct + 1

                                'check begining of page if yes enter PDF page number for any idenfication

                                If Yes_Fir Then
                                    RW_Ct = RW_Ct + 1
                                    .Cells(RW_Ct, Col_Num).Value = "Text In Page - " & i
                                    RW_Ct = RW_Ct + 2
                                    Yes_Fir = False
                                End If

                                'check for maximum rows if exceeds start from next column

                                If RW_Ct > Li_Row Then
                                    RW_Ct = 1
                                    Col_Num = Col_Num + 1
                                End If

                                T_Str = CStr(Hld_Txt(k))
                                If Left(T_Str, 1) = "=" Then T_Str = "'" & T_Str
                                .Cells(RW_Ct, Col_Num).Value = T_Str

                            Next k

                                Else

                                    RW_Ct = RW_Ct + 1
                                    .Cells(RW_Ct, Col_Num).Value = "No text found in page " & i
                                    RW_Ct = RW_Ct + 1

                        End If

            End If

        End With
    Next i

    .Close

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Imported"

h_end:

Set WS_PDF = Nothing
Set AC_PGTxt = Nothing
Set AC_PG = Nothing
Set AC_Hi = Nothing
Set AC_PD = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to do something with each table in the document:

```
Dim oTbl As Table

For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    ' Do something
    Debug.Print oTbl.Columns.Count & " " & oTbl.Rows.Count
Next
```

You'll need to figure out how you want the user to specify which table/tables to work with.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
Sub UserChosenTables()
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim aTables() As String
    Dim x As Long

    sTemp = InputBox("Which tables", "Select tables")

    If Len(sTemp) = 0 Then ' user entered nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    aTables = Split(sTemp, ",")

    ' of course you'll want to add more code to CYA in case the user
    ' asks for a table that's not there or otherwise enters something silly.
    ' You might also want to let them enter e.g. ALL if they want you to do all of them
    ' (but don't know how many there are)
    For x = LBound(aTables) To UBound(aTables)
        Set oTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(CLng(aTables(x)))
        ' do [whatever] with table here
        Debug.Print oTbl.Columns.Count & " " & oTbl.Rows.Count
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error message, unless I change as Table to as Object, then when i input a number of for the number of tables i get more errors. Can you please be a little more specific,i have limited experience with vba. Thanks

Comment: Table vs Object:  if you're using VBA within Word, that shouldn't be necessary, but if you're driving Word from another app or programming language, it would be; no problem there.  When entering the table numbers, enter e.g.  1,3,5 to have it work with tables 1, 3 and 5.  Obviously, more errortrapping is needed for production code.  If that doesn't help, let us know what specific errors you get and on which lines.  Post the ACTUAL code you're using now.

Comment: I got adobe installed so now can use this vba code to import pdf docs into excel. But I need help in modifying the code so that it only imports tables from the pdf, rather than all the contents.

Comment: In Outlook, messages and other items use MS Word table objects.  You can reference the tables in variable dimmed `As Word.Table`.